# Using Core Data migrations without Xcode data designer

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration, rubymotion

I'm using Core Data with Rubymotion, and I don't want to use the Xcode graphical data modeller, I'm just creating a bunch of NSEntityDescriptions and NSEntityAttributes in code, and it works great.

- But I haven't figured out if it is possible to use Core Data schema migrations without creating the .xcdatamodeld files?
- And also, if it's not possible to run migrations without .xcdatamodeld files, maybe there are some libs that can generate the required files from NSEntityDescriptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how MotionData is trying to achieve this.
https://github.com/alloy/MotionData/blob/master/app/schema.rb#L108
Probably we have to play with [NSMigrationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMigrationManager_class/Reference/NSMigrationManager.html). See their spec and how it might be able to use it https://github.com/alloy/MotionData/blob/master/spec/schema_spec.rb#L146
Please share us if you are able to figure this out. I am trying to solve the exact same problem too.